# How to sort ArrayList of objects by alphabetical order of property

Tags: java, list, sorting, object, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of People, with every person having their names or ages.
So, I'll be adding new people to this ArrayList and I want to sort it alphabetically.
For example:

```
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
list.add(new Person("Matt", 23));
list.add(new Person("John", 34));
```

If a print the names of the list of course I will receive John first as that's the first Person I added, so how can I sort it so John can be the first one alphabetically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use rule bases collator, I am sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: Check out `Collections.sort` and the `Comparators.comparing` utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `Comparator<Person>` Interface or Person class should implement `Comparable` interface. In the `compareTo` or `compare` method you can implement the comparison logic to sort based on name of the property as per your requirement.